# what if I switch the positive and negative power supply of an amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier

If the original output of an amplifier is 10V, when I switch the positive and negative power supply, will the output become -10V or anything else?

Comment: in the best case scenario, some protection device will not let current flow and nothing will turn on. worst case scenario, something is going to blow up.

Comment: Take a cheap OpAmp which you can part with, stick it on a breadboard, give it a try, look for smoke.

Comment: How would you like if somebody were feeding you in the opposite direction? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The amplifier is likely to either drag down your power rails or go up in smoke depending on how much current your power rails can provide.

Answer (score 0):

it really depends...
carbon button amplifiers will operate just fine with supply reversed, but more modern devices not so much.